# Retrieve Jira ID after Creating A Jira

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I wanted to check if there was a way to return a issue ID after sending a request for one.

Below is my code

```
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'id': 123},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

Is there a way, I can retrieve the issue ID here or do I need to setup another query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=issue#jira.JIRA.create_issue) `create_issue` will return an `Issue` which has the  ID and the issue key.

```
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'id': 123},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
print(new_issue.id)
print(new_issue.key)
```